# C++ container with deactivating elements

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I need to iterate through a container of elements and in some cases (when an event happens) I need to deactivate a certain element so that iteration through the container doesn't take into account such element. However, after some time this element is activated and it should appear in iteration.

My choice is to use std::list, however it can be much time consuming inserting and removing an element. There is a better option?

Comment: inserting and removing from a list is fast and cheap, also how many elements are we talking here?

Comment: It can vary, from small number to really huge ones. However, let's consider small number.

Comment: Your comment has not answered my question, the fact remains insertion and deletion from a list is fast

Comment: I thought about using map where keys are elements and values are activation flags, elements are omitted, when activation flags is false.

Comment: You can use a container for the actual elements, and an std::list of pointers to add/remove elements fast.

Comment: Have a look at [boost::filter_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html).

Comment: Why keep adding and removing the item?  Isn't a member function `isActive()` enough, and you just skip over the ones that return `false`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree with you. However, it depends on the problem itself. Consider a list of 10.000 elements used quite often, when an event happens and e.g. 5000 have to be deactived (and stay deactived for some time) it would be probably faster to remove them once from the list and don't have to iterate over them later!? (I know OP says that there are not that many elements, want just to point it out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your own iterable class based on lists or whatever container suits your needs best.

This new container should have methods to mark an item valid/invalid, and an iterator that would go over all elements of the underlying container but skip the ones that have been marked invalid.

If speed is an issue, you could add whatever optimization you fancy in your new class in order to minimize iterations over the underlying container (storing ranges of valid elements, for instance).

Comment: What's an "iterable class"? Did you mean container?

Comment: Yes indeed that's what I meant